# Parallel Programming Vector Addition

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is vector addition being processed sequentially faster than being processed in parallel due to overhead in mpi? I have used mpi by scattering two arrays then processing a certain number of vectors pairs locally for each slave and then perform a gather to send all values back to the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is totally expected. Vector addition is dominated by the cost to read and write the values from memory. An addition is orders of magnitude faster than reading/writing one element from memory. Attempting to scatter/add/gather is futile to improve performance. To gain performance from scatter/gather you must either perform a very expensive operation on each data element or use each data element multiple times.

In an idiomatic MPI program, the vectors should exist distributed in the first place.

Edit: The same holds true for Vector / Matrix multiplication given that each element of the matrix is accessed only once.

Comment: Is this also true for matrix vector multiplication?

Comment: Yes, since each element of the matrix is accessed only once.